# How do I use RxJS Observable in Chrome or Firefox developer tools console?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to quickly test some Observable related functions. In my Chrome Developper Tools (or the Firefox one, doesn't matter).

It seems to me that some days ago I was able to simply execute code like this :

```
var test$ = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]);
```

directly in my JavaScript console. My recollection seems even more correct since I actually have digged up this example (and many others) from my dev tools console history !

---

For some reason, it is not working anymore; I get this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Rx is not defined

or if I just use Observable instead of Rx.Observable

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Observable is not defined

---

It is not possible to use `import` statement 'as is' in the Chrome console. Does someone has a solution to debug RxJS code in using browser's Javascript console ?

Comment: I just created a website called https://rxjs.rxplayground.com/. It supports most major Rxjs version, has autocomplete and you can stop your runaway subscriptions with the stop button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## UPDATE 2020-Dec :

RxJS in browser'sconsole is back!

Just go to https://rxjs.dev/ and open devtools console :)

```
 ____           _ ____      
|  _ \ __  __  | / ___|    
| |_) |\ \/ /  | \___ \  
|  _ <  >  < |_| |___) |    
|_| \_\/_/\_\___/|____/ 

started experimenting with RxJS:

type this into the console:

rxjs.interval(500).pipe(rxjs.operators.take(4)).subscribe(console.log)
```

### UPDATE 2018-Nov :

I just noticed that my previous answer (and the accepted one) is not valid anymore. The https://reactive.io site now redirects to https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/ and shows this :

```
 ____           _ ____      
|  _ \ __  __  | / ___|    
| |_) |\ \/ /  | \___ \  
|  _ <  >  < |_| |___) |    
|_| \_\/_/\_\___/|____/ 

Open http://stackblitz.com and try this code to get
started experimenting with RxJS:

import { interval } from "rxjs"

import { take } from "rxjs/operators"

const subscription = interval(500).pipe(take(4)).subscribe(console.log)
```

So now [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) is the "official" way to go.

### Original post :

After going back to the [ReactiveX documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/), I had the confirmation by looking at this at the bottom :

> Hint: open your DevTools to experiment with RxJS.

I simply forgot that this is available only if you open the dev tools **[from the reactivex.io/rxjs page itself](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/)** :

[image: RxJS in Chrome developer tools]

Comment: uh, yeah - there are lots and lots of JavaScript libraries and packages out there, and your browser doesn't come with them

Comment: @AndrewKoper sure, but in this case the fact that this one was loaded with the website is quite handy

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The Rx Library is loaded when the site is loaded, you can access it directly [reactive.io](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/). This will work there</strike>

```
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Still valid?
> Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]);
> VM238:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Rx is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: There seems to be an issue with their website. It throws a 503. The url I am trying is https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/